# Deliver email from local development server

Tags: centos, email, postfix, email-server

I'm working on a website development and need to test some email stuff (send email to register users just me and I'm using my personal email address for this purpose). I'm not an expert so I only have installed Postfix, it's not configured and I don't know how to do it or even if it's possible. As OS I'm using CentOS 6.5 and I'm running it in a Vmware Virtual Machine that have two network cards: one with NAT connection sharing Internet with host and the other is a internal card with local address for connect trough Putty and so on.

I don't really need to deliver the email, but will be nice if I could, just see their content to watch behavior. I send some emails from PHP site and then check `/var/log/maillog` using `tail` and this is the output:

```
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/pickup[16879]: 5E2BFA4B38: uid=48 from=<no-reply@alomicuba.com>
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/cleanup[16891]: 5E2BFA4B38: message-id=<53a0b06154856@alomicuba.com>
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/qmgr[16880]: 5E2BFA4B38: from=<no-reply@alomicuba.com>, size=1773, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/smtp[16893]: 5E2BFA4B38: to=<reynierpm@gmail.com>, relay=192.168.1.101[192.168.1.101]:25, delay=0.05, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host 192.168.1.101[192.168.1.101] said: 530 SMTP authentication is required. (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/cleanup[16891]: 67EE6A4B37: message-id=<20140617211721.67EE6A4B37@localhost.localdomain>
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/qmgr[16880]: 67EE6A4B37: from=<>, size=3752, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/bounce[16894]: 5E2BFA4B38: sender non-delivery notification: 67EE6A4B37
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/qmgr[16880]: 5E2BFA4B38: removed
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/smtp[16893]: 67EE6A4B37: to=<no-reply@alomicuba.com>, relay=192.168.1.101[192.168.1.101]:25, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host 192.168.1.101[192.168.1.101] said: 530 SMTP authentication is required. (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Jun 17 16:47:21 localhost postfix/qmgr[16880]: 67EE6A4B37: removed
```

But if I run the command `postqueue -p` I get `Mail queue is empty` where that emails go? I need to see their content using `postcat -vq XXXXXXXXXX` but I can't get the ID since there is not emails, why? Any advice or help?

**postconf command output**

```
2bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
access_map_defer_code = 450
access_map_reject_code = 554
address_verify_default_transport = $default_transport
address_verify_local_transport = $local_transport
address_verify_map =
address_verify_negative_cache = yes
address_verify_negative_expire_time = 3d
address_verify_negative_refresh_time = 3h
address_verify_poll_count = ${stress?1}${stress:3}
address_verify_poll_delay = 3s
address_verify_positive_expire_time = 31d
address_verify_positive_refresh_time = 7d
address_verify_relay_transport = $relay_transport
address_verify_relayhost = $relayhost
address_verify_sender = $double_bounce_sender
address_verify_sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
address_verify_service_name = verify
address_verify_transport_maps = $transport_maps
address_verify_virtual_transport = $virtual_transport
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_mail_to_commands = alias, forward
allow_mail_to_files = alias, forward
allow_min_user = no
allow_percent_hack = yes
allow_untrusted_routing = no
alternate_config_directories =
always_add_missing_headers = no
always_bcc =
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
anvil_status_update_time = 600s
append_at_myorigin = yes
append_dot_mydomain = yes
application_event_drain_time = 100s
authorized_flush_users = static:anyone
authorized_mailq_users = static:anyone
authorized_submit_users = static:anyone
backwards_bounce_logfile_compatibility = yes
berkeley_db_create_buffer_size = 16777216
berkeley_db_read_buffer_size = 131072
best_mx_transport =
biff = yes
body_checks =
body_checks_size_limit = 51200
bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
bounce_queue_lifetime = 5d
bounce_service_name = bounce
bounce_size_limit = 50000
bounce_template_file =
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
canonical_classes = envelope_sender, envelope_recipient, header_sender, header_recipient
canonical_maps =
cleanup_service_name = cleanup
command_directory = /usr/sbin
command_execution_directory =
command_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
command_time_limit = 1000s
config_directory = /etc/postfix
connection_cache_protocol_timeout = 5s
connection_cache_service_name = scache
connection_cache_status_update_time = 600s
connection_cache_ttl_limit = 2s
content_filter =
cyrus_sasl_config_path =
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
default_database_type = hash
default_delivery_slot_cost = 5
default_delivery_slot_discount = 50
default_delivery_slot_loan = 3
default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = 1
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20
default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = 1
default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = 1
default_destination_rate_delay = 0s
default_destination_recipient_limit = 50
default_extra_recipient_limit = 1000
default_minimum_delivery_slots = 3
default_privs = nobody
default_process_limit = 100
default_rbl_reply = $rbl_code Service unavailable; $rbl_class [$rbl_what] blocked using $rbl_domain${rbl_reason?; $rbl_reason}
default_recipient_limit = 20000
default_recipient_refill_delay = 5s
default_recipient_refill_limit = 100
default_transport = smtp
default_verp_delimiters = +=
defer_code = 450
defer_service_name = defer
defer_transports =
delay_logging_resolution_limit = 2
delay_notice_recipient = postmaster
delay_warning_time = 0h
deliver_lock_attempts = 20
deliver_lock_delay = 1s
destination_concurrency_feedback_debug = no
detect_8bit_encoding_header = yes
disable_dns_lookups = no
disable_mime_input_processing = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
disable_verp_bounces = no
disable_vrfy_command = no
dont_remove = 0
double_bounce_sender = double-bounce
duplicate_filter_limit = 1000
empty_address_recipient = MAILER-DAEMON
empty_address_relayhost_maps_lookup_key = <>
enable_original_recipient = yes
error_notice_recipient = postmaster
error_service_name = error
execution_directory_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
expand_owner_alias = no
export_environment = TZ MAIL_CONFIG LANG
fallback_transport =
fallback_transport_maps =
fast_flush_domains = $relay_domains
fast_flush_purge_time = 7d
fast_flush_refresh_time = 12h
fault_injection_code = 0
flush_service_name = flush
fork_attempts = 5
fork_delay = 1s
forward_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
forward_path = $home/.forward${recipient_delimiter}${extension}, $home/.forward
frozen_delivered_to = yes
hash_queue_depth = 1
hash_queue_names = deferred, defer
header_address_token_limit = 10240
header_checks =
header_size_limit = 102400
helpful_warnings = yes
home_mailbox =
hopcount_limit = 50
html_directory = no
ignore_mx_lookup_error = no
import_environment = MAIL_CONFIG MAIL_DEBUG MAIL_LOGTAG TZ XAUTHORITY DISPLAY LANG=C
in_flow_delay = 1s
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
initial_destination_concurrency = 5
internal_mail_filter_classes =
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 501
ipc_idle = 5s
ipc_timeout = 3600s
ipc_ttl = 1000s
line_length_limit = 2048
lmtp_assume_final = no
lmtp_bind_address =
lmtp_bind_address6 =
lmtp_body_checks =
lmtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
lmtp_connect_timeout = 0s
lmtp_connection_cache_destinations =
lmtp_connection_cache_on_demand = yes
lmtp_connection_cache_time_limit = 2s
lmtp_connection_reuse_time_limit = 300s
lmtp_data_done_timeout = 600s
lmtp_data_init_timeout = 120s
lmtp_data_xfer_timeout = 180s
lmtp_defer_if_no_mx_address_found = no
lmtp_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
lmtp_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
lmtp_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
lmtp_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
lmtp_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
lmtp_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
lmtp_discard_lhlo_keyword_address_maps =
lmtp_discard_lhlo_keywords =
lmtp_enforce_tls = no
lmtp_generic_maps =
lmtp_header_checks =
lmtp_host_lookup = dns
lmtp_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
lmtp_lhlo_name = $myhostname
lmtp_lhlo_timeout = 300s
lmtp_line_length_limit = 990
lmtp_mail_timeout = 300s
lmtp_mime_header_checks =
lmtp_mx_address_limit = 5
lmtp_mx_session_limit = 2
lmtp_nested_header_checks =
lmtp_pix_workaround_delay_time = 10s
lmtp_pix_workaround_maps =
lmtp_pix_workaround_threshold_time = 500s
lmtp_pix_workarounds = disable_esmtp,delay_dotcrlf
lmtp_quit_timeout = 300s
lmtp_quote_rfc821_envelope = yes
lmtp_randomize_addresses = yes
lmtp_rcpt_timeout = 300s
lmtp_rset_timeout = 20s
lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name =
lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_time = 90d
lmtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
lmtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
lmtp_sasl_mechanism_filter =
lmtp_sasl_password_maps =
lmtp_sasl_path =
lmtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
lmtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $lmtp_sasl_security_options
lmtp_sasl_type = cyrus
lmtp_send_xforward_command = no
lmtp_sender_dependent_authentication = no
lmtp_skip_5xx_greeting = yes
lmtp_skip_quit_response = no
lmtp_starttls_timeout = 300s
lmtp_tcp_port = 24
lmtp_tls_CAfile =
lmtp_tls_CApath =
lmtp_tls_cert_file =
lmtp_tls_ciphers = export
lmtp_tls_dcert_file =
lmtp_tls_dkey_file = $lmtp_tls_dcert_file
lmtp_tls_eccert_file =
lmtp_tls_eckey_file = $lmtp_tls_eccert_file
lmtp_tls_enforce_peername = yes
lmtp_tls_exclude_ciphers =
lmtp_tls_fingerprint_cert_match =
lmtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
lmtp_tls_key_file = $lmtp_tls_cert_file
lmtp_tls_loglevel = 0
lmtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
lmtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers =
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
lmtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = no
lmtp_tls_per_site =
lmtp_tls_policy_maps =
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2
lmtp_tls_scert_verifydepth = 9
lmtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop
lmtp_tls_security_level =
lmtp_tls_session_cache_database =
lmtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
lmtp_tls_verify_cert_match = hostname
lmtp_use_tls = no
lmtp_xforward_timeout = 300s
local_command_shell =
local_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
local_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
local_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
local_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
local_destination_recipient_limit = 1
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_inet_interfaces
local_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
local_transport = local:$myhostname
luser_relay =
mail_name = Postfix
mail_owner = postfix
mail_release_date = 20100319
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
mail_version = 2.6.6
mailbox_command =
mailbox_command_maps =
mailbox_delivery_lock = fcntl, dotlock
mailbox_size_limit = 51200000
mailbox_transport =
mailbox_transport_maps =
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
maps_rbl_domains =
maps_rbl_reject_code = 554
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains =
masquerade_exceptions =
master_service_disable =
max_idle = 100s
max_use = 100
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 5d
message_reject_characters =
message_size_limit = 10240000
message_strip_characters =
milter_command_timeout = 30s
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v
milter_connect_timeout = 30s
milter_content_timeout = 300s
milter_data_macros = i
milter_default_action = tempfail
milter_end_of_data_macros = i
milter_end_of_header_macros = i
milter_helo_macros = {tls_version} {cipher} {cipher_bits} {cert_subject} {cert_issuer}
milter_macro_daemon_name = $myhostname
milter_macro_v = $mail_name $mail_version
milter_mail_macros = i {auth_type} {auth_authen} {auth_author} {mail_addr} {mail_host} {mail_mailer}
milter_protocol = 6
milter_rcpt_macros = i {rcpt_addr} {rcpt_host} {rcpt_mailer}
milter_unknown_command_macros =
mime_boundary_length_limit = 2048
mime_header_checks = $header_checks
mime_nesting_limit = 100
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
multi_instance_directories =
multi_instance_enable = no
multi_instance_group =
multi_instance_name =
multi_instance_wrapper =
multi_recipient_bounce_reject_code = 550
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = localdomain
myhostname = localhost.localdomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = $myhostname
nested_header_checks = $header_checks
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_fqdn_reject_code = 504
non_smtpd_milters =
notify_classes = resource, software
owner_request_special = yes
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
permit_mx_backup_networks =
pickup_service_name = pickup
plaintext_reject_code = 450
postmulti_control_commands = reload flush
postmulti_start_commands = start
postmulti_stop_commands = stop abort drain quick-stop
prepend_delivered_header = command, file, forward
process_id_directory = pid
propagate_unmatched_extensions = canonical, virtual
proxy_interfaces =
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $sender_bcc_maps $recipient_bcc_maps $smtp_generic_maps $lmtp_generic_maps
proxy_write_maps = $smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name $lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name
proxymap_service_name = proxymap
proxywrite_service_name = proxywrite
qmgr_clog_warn_time = 300s
qmgr_fudge_factor = 100
qmgr_message_active_limit = 20000
qmgr_message_recipient_limit = 20000
qmgr_message_recipient_minimum = 10
qmqpd_authorized_clients =
qmqpd_client_port_logging = no
qmqpd_error_delay = 1s
qmqpd_timeout = 300s
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
queue_file_attribute_count_limit = 100
queue_minfree = 0
queue_run_delay = 300s
queue_service_name = qmgr
rbl_reply_maps =
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
receive_override_options =
recipient_bcc_maps =
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient, header_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps =
recipient_delimiter =
reject_code = 554
reject_tempfail_action = defer_if_permit
relay_clientcerts =
relay_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
relay_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
relay_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
relay_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
relay_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
relay_domains = prueba.com
relay_domains_reject_code = 554
relay_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
relay_recipient_maps =
relay_transport = relay
relayhost = 192.168.1.101
relocated_maps =
remote_header_rewrite_domain =
require_home_directory = no
resolve_dequoted_address = yes
resolve_null_domain = no
resolve_numeric_domain = no
rewrite_service_name = rewrite
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
send_cyrus_sasl_authzid = no
sender_bcc_maps =
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender
sender_canonical_maps =
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps =
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
service_throttle_time = 60s
setgid_group = postdrop
show_user_unknown_table_name = yes
showq_service_name = showq
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_bind_address =
smtp_bind_address6 =
smtp_body_checks =
smtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
smtp_connect_timeout = 30s
smtp_connection_cache_destinations =
smtp_connection_cache_on_demand = yes
smtp_connection_cache_time_limit = 2s
smtp_connection_reuse_time_limit = 300s
smtp_data_done_timeout = 600s
smtp_data_init_timeout = 120s
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 180s
smtp_defer_if_no_mx_address_found = no
smtp_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
smtp_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
smtp_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
smtp_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
smtp_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
smtp_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps =
smtp_discard_ehlo_keywords =
smtp_enforce_tls = no
smtp_fallback_relay = $fallback_relay
smtp_generic_maps =
smtp_header_checks =
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
smtp_helo_timeout = 300s
smtp_host_lookup = dns
smtp_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
smtp_line_length_limit = 990
smtp_mail_timeout = 300s
smtp_mime_header_checks =
smtp_mx_address_limit = 5
smtp_mx_session_limit = 2
smtp_nested_header_checks =
smtp_never_send_ehlo = no
smtp_pix_workaround_delay_time = 10s
smtp_pix_workaround_maps =
smtp_pix_workaround_threshold_time = 500s
smtp_pix_workarounds = disable_esmtp,delay_dotcrlf
smtp_quit_timeout = 300s
smtp_quote_rfc821_envelope = yes
smtp_randomize_addresses = yes
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 300s
smtp_rset_timeout = 20s
smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name =
smtp_sasl_auth_cache_time = 90d
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter =
smtp_sasl_password_maps =
smtp_sasl_path =
smtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtp_sasl_security_options
smtp_sasl_tls_verified_security_options = $smtp_sasl_tls_security_options
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_send_xforward_command = no
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = no
smtp_skip_5xx_greeting = yes
smtp_skip_quit_response = yes
smtp_starttls_timeout = 300s
smtp_tls_CAfile =
smtp_tls_CApath =
smtp_tls_cert_file =
smtp_tls_ciphers = export
smtp_tls_dcert_file =
smtp_tls_dkey_file = $smtp_tls_dcert_file
smtp_tls_eccert_file =
smtp_tls_eckey_file = $smtp_tls_eccert_file
smtp_tls_enforce_peername = yes
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers =
smtp_tls_fingerprint_cert_match =
smtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
smtp_tls_key_file = $smtp_tls_cert_file
smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers =
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = no
smtp_tls_per_site =
smtp_tls_policy_maps =
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2
smtp_tls_scert_verifydepth = 9
smtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop, dot-nexthop
smtp_tls_security_level =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database =
smtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtp_tls_verify_cert_match = hostname
smtp_use_tls = no
smtp_xforward_timeout = 300s
smtpd_authorized_verp_clients = $authorized_verp_clients
smtpd_authorized_xclient_hosts =
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 50
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions = ${smtpd_client_connection_limit_exceptions:$mynetworks}
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_port_logging = no
smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_data_restrictions =
smtpd_delay_open_until_valid_rcpt = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps =
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords =
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
smtpd_enforce_tls = no
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_etrn_restrictions =
smtpd_expansion_filter = \t\40!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
smtpd_forbidden_commands = CONNECT GET POST
smtpd_hard_error_limit = ${stress?1}${stress:20}
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_history_flush_threshold = 100
smtpd_junk_command_limit = ${stress?1}${stress:100}
smtpd_milters =
smtpd_noop_commands =
smtpd_null_access_lookup_key = <>
smtpd_peername_lookup = yes
smtpd_policy_service_max_idle = 300s
smtpd_policy_service_max_ttl = 1000s
smtpd_policy_service_timeout = 100s
smtpd_proxy_ehlo = $myhostname
smtpd_proxy_filter =
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 100s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_overshoot_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
smtpd_restriction_classes =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks =
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_starttls_timeout = 300s
smtpd_timeout = ${stress?10}${stress:300}s
smtpd_tls_CAfile =
smtpd_tls_CApath =
smtpd_tls_always_issue_session_ids = yes
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_ccert_verifydepth = 9
smtpd_tls_cert_file =
smtpd_tls_ciphers = export
smtpd_tls_dcert_file =
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file =
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file =
smtpd_tls_dkey_file = $smtpd_tls_dcert_file
smtpd_tls_eccert_file =
smtpd_tls_eckey_file = $smtpd_tls_eccert_file
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = none
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers =
smtpd_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers =
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_protocols =
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_tls_req_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_security_level =
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database =
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_wrappermode = no
smtpd_use_tls = no
soft_bounce = no
stale_lock_time = 500s
stress =
strict_7bit_headers = no
strict_8bitmime = no
strict_8bitmime_body = no
strict_mailbox_ownership = yes
strict_mime_encoding_domain = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
sun_mailtool_compatibility = no
swap_bangpath = yes
syslog_facility = mail
syslog_name = ${multi_instance_name:postfix}${multi_instance_name?$multi_instance_name}
tcp_windowsize = 0
tls_daemon_random_bytes = 32
tls_eecdh_strong_curve = prime256v1
tls_eecdh_ultra_curve = secp384r1
tls_export_cipherlist = ALL:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_high_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:!LOW:!MEDIUM:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_low_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_medium_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:!LOW:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_null_cipherlist = eNULL:!aNULL
tls_random_bytes = 32
tls_random_exchange_name = ${data_directory}/prng_exch
tls_random_prng_update_period = 3600s
tls_random_reseed_period = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
trace_service_name = trace
transport_maps =
transport_retry_time = 60s
trigger_timeout = 10s
undisclosed_recipients_header = To: undisclosed-recipients:;
unknown_address_reject_code = 450
unknown_address_tempfail_action = $reject_tempfail_action
unknown_client_reject_code = 450
unknown_helo_hostname_tempfail_action = $reject_tempfail_action
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 450
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unknown_relay_recipient_reject_code = 550
unknown_virtual_alias_reject_code = 550
unknown_virtual_mailbox_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_defer_code = 450
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 450
unverified_recipient_reject_reason =
unverified_recipient_tempfail_action = $reject_tempfail_action
unverified_sender_defer_code = 450
unverified_sender_reject_code = 450
unverified_sender_reject_reason =
unverified_sender_tempfail_action = $reject_tempfail_action
verp_delimiter_filter = -=+
virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps
virtual_alias_expansion_limit = 1000
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps
virtual_alias_recursion_limit = 1000
virtual_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
virtual_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
virtual_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
virtual_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
virtual_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
virtual_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
virtual_gid_maps =
virtual_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
virtual_mailbox_base =
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_lock = fcntl, dotlock
virtual_mailbox_maps =
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps =
```

**Trying to configure Gmail as relay**

I followed every step on [this guide](http://mhawthorne.net/posts/postfix-configuring-gmail-as-relay.html) and now after restart the `postfix` service and check logs I get this:

```
Jun 17 17:50:37 localhost postfix/postfix-script[17953]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Jun 17 17:50:37 localhost postfix/master[17903]: terminating on signal 15
Jun 17 17:50:37 localhost postfix/postfix-script[18025]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jun 17 17:50:37 localhost postfix/master[18026]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 17 17:50:37 localhost postfix/qmgr[18029]: AB33EA4B38: from=<no-reply@alomicuba.com>, size=1773, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 17 17:50:37 localhost postfix/smtp[18031]: fatal: open database /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db: Invalid argument
Jun 17 17:50:38 localhost postfix/master[18026]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp pid 18031 exit status 1
Jun 17 17:50:38 localhost postfix/master[18026]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
```

I've created the file `sasl_passwd.db` by typing `nano sasl_passwd.db` and writing this content inside `[smtp.gmail.com]:587  username:password` as guide said (of course changing the username:password values for the right ones), what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your postfix server is requiring authentication to send mails to outside domains:

```
530 SMTP authentication is required
```

This is in your log. You should've read this.

To fix this you must either authenticate with an username or disable the authentication requirements in postfix.

To disable authentication from your network you need to type this in the command line:

```
postconf -e mynetworks=192.168.1.0/24
```

Or edit the file `main.cf` in the postfix folder, probably in `/etc/postifx` with the following contents:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.1.0/24
```

Considering that your internal network is 192.168.1.0 and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I fix that? I'm not a Postfix expert just a developer trying to test things

Comment: Test with the postconf command and report success here...

Comment: Done, added to main post

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: I make changes at `/etc/postfix/main.cf` as you suggest, then restart postfix `service postfix restart`, then try sending a email again to my gmail and the error still

Comment: If you're relaying to Gmail, try to authenticate in Gmail with your credentials. Take a look here: http://mhawthorne.net/posts/postfix-configuring-gmail-as-relay.html

Comment: Take a look at my latest edition, I can't get this to work :-(

Comment: Have you run the postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd command?

Comment: Hmm I was doing wrong but I fixed that now I get this other error `warning: TLS library problem: 18332:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:169:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt','r'):` how do I fix that one?

Comment: This is another problem, Reynier. The certificate chain appears to be broken. Do you have ca-certificates installed? Try `yum search certificates` and see if there is a ca-certificates package. If yes, install it.

Comment: Thanks I found where the error is and it was caused because Fedora 19 doesn’t have the ca-certificates.crt file anymore and I assume CentOS either so I changed from `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` and now the postfix is relaying emails trough Gmail, many thanks for your help